# Differences between java.rmi.server.hostname and com.sun.management.jmxremote.host

Tags: monitoring, jmx

When enabling JMX remote connection, I saw these two properties, java.rmi.server.hostname and com.sun.management.jmxremote.host. What the differences between these two?

Answer (score 3):

The initial connection from the client (e.g. `jconsole` or `visualvm`) is established to `com.sun.management.jmxremote.host` on port
`com.sun.management.jmxremote.port`. Then the connecting client obtains `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` (it is dynamically assigned by Java from a pool of unused ports if not explicitly specified) and further communication and data exchange goes over Java RMI connecting to `java.rmi.server.hostname` on port `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port`.

If you don't use JMX authentication or SSL I'd recommend configuring both hosts as localhost (see configuration example below).

```
java.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
com.sun.management.jmxremote
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9091
com.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1
com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9092
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

You can connect to such process either from the same machine or via SSH with port forwarding e.g.

```
ssh user@host -L 9091:localhost:9091 -L 9092:localhost:9092
```